# How to place child divs one below the other without wasting space, in a compact manner?

Tags: html, css

[image]
I have 4 divs within a parent div. Since the 3rd div is taller than the rest, the 4th one is placed below the 3rd one even though there is space above. There is no padding/margin etc. given to the 4th div. I want it to move up and occupy the space available.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Can you give us some code snippets for your html, or an idea of what the divs would look life before and after?

Answer (score 1):

Give the following classes to your parent div and fourth div.

```
.parentDiv{
    position:relative;
}

.fourth-div{
    position:absolute;
    top: exact Height of second-div + margin;   // Calculation
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: The div heights aren't constant, so I'll have to set this using Js/jQuery which I want to avoid if possible.